# Travel document for baby born in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, family, documentation

My baby was born in the UK, but doesn't have a passport yet. Our tier 2 visa expires soon and we won't be able to get a passport from our country until then. Is there any type of document that allows to travel outside of the UK?

Comment: I would suggest asking your country's embassy/consulate in the UK whether they can provide an emergency travel document, or, for that matter, a passport on an expedited basis.

Comment: Also, for all questions of this type, it is helpful to mention your own citizenship, so people reading the question have as much context as possible in order to answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for this situation you will certainly need a travel document from your baby's country of citizenship. These go by various names, such as:

- Emergency passport
- Emergency travel document
- Provisional travel document

For example, Australia can issue a [Provisional Travel Document](https://www.passports.gov.au/pages/travel-related-documents.aspx):

> A Provisional Travel Document (PTD) is generally issued in an emergency situation overseas to enable an Australian to travel to the nearest passport-issuing authority.
>
> To obtain a PTD, you should contact the nearest Australian diplomatic mission or consulate  to discuss your individual circumstances.

In your situation, you should contact your country's consulate or embassy as soon as possible to obtain a travel document for your baby.

Answer (score 0):

If your country of citizenship has an embassy in the UK, it is probable that they can issue your baby with a passport. Or at least give you advice about what you can do in these circumstances.

Be aware that getting a passport while overseas can take much longer than getting one within your country of citizenship, so it would be best to apply as soon as you can.